# Check if loaded assembly is domain neutral

Tags: c#, assemblies

I've installed a few assemblies in GAC. Now, I'm loading them dynamicly in separate AppDomains.

Is there way to check if they are loaded as domain neutral assemblies?

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to know if assembly is domain neutral?

Comment: I've try to figure out if it will help me to improve memory efficiency.  I installed assemblies in GAC, but this nothing change in memory usage (but assemblies are loaded from GAC). I'm creating a lot of AppDomains and each of them need ~20MB. I suppose that this should something cut out, so maybe I do something wrong.
Also, I'm just curious :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. Just use Process Explorer, get details of the process and then go to .Net Assemblies tab. But it need to run Process Explorer as administartor.